# Enable PL011 UART transmit/receive FIFO

Tags: uart

How can we set pl011 uart with transmit fifo and receive fifo enable in raspberry pi?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do anything.

The PL011 UART is enabled by default as device /dev/ttyAMA0.  The Linux driver handles the FIFOs and has additional buffering.

Comment: Also...I believe if you disabled it at some point and want to re-enable it you can do so via `sudo raspi-config` under `advanced options` in the newest version of Raspbian?.